# Remove inline styles from text

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm using [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) which is a javascript text editor. My problem is, when I paste text from another site into the editor, it adopts the style of the text from that site. How can I prevent this?

My editor is rendered in my Django template like this:

```
{{ post.content }}
```

Is there a template tag I can use to remove HTML? Because the external styling is inline styles, e.g. `<span style='font-family: Arial;font-size:30px'` etc..?

Comment: You can turn escaping off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove styles from a formatted paste (styles pasted from clipboard) in [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/), set the [**`removeformatPasted`**](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation/#remove-format-pasted) option to `true`:

```
$('.trumbowyg').trumbowyg({
  removeformatPasted: true
});
```

**But also keep in mind:**

- In order to use this option, you need to define a **font size** in your CSS **or use a reset** like normalize.
- Remove format pasted is not active by default (set to `false`).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm not really sure what this means "in order to use this option, you need to define a font size in your CSS", and maybe that's the issue. Is there some property in the trumbowyg API where a font-size is set? Or are you saying that somewhere in the page CSS there needs to be a font size set, like 'body{ font-size: 12pt}'

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove HTML tags? If yes just use:

```
{{ post.content|striptags }}
```